# How can I change the current URL in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

On my website:

```
http://mywebsite.com/1.html
```

I want to use the

```javascript
window.location.pathname
```

to get the last part of the URL:

```
1.html
```

and since I have all my webpages in numbers, I want to add 1 to the current URL, so that when I click a button, it will redirect me to the next page:

```javascript
var url = 'http://mywebsite.com/' + window.location.pathname;
function nextImage () {
    url = url + 1;
}
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: You're just adding 1 to the url.  You need to increment the numerical portion of the filename - #.html

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Your example wasn't working because you are trying to add 1 to a string that looks like this: "1.html".  That will just get you this "1.html1" which is not what you want.  You have to isolate the numeric part of the string and then convert it to an actual number before you can do math on it.  After getting it to an actual number, you can then increase its value and then combine it back with the rest of the string.

You can use a custom replace function like this to isolate the various pieces of the original URL and replace the number with an incremented number:

```
function nextImage() {
    return(window.location.href.replace(/(\d+)(\.html)$/, function(str, p1, p2) {
        return((Number(p1) + 1) + p2);
    }));
}
```

You can then call it like this:

```
window.location.href = nextImage();
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/3VPEq/

This will work for any URL that ends in some series of digits followed by .html and if you needed a slightly different URL form, you could just tweak the regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

This is more robust:

```
mi = location.href.split(/(\d+)/);
no = mi.length - 2;
os = mi[no];
mi[no]++;
if ((mi[no] + '').length < os.length) mi[no] = os.match(/0+/) + mi[no];
location.href = mi.join('');
```

When the URL has multiple numbers, it will change the last one:

```
http://mywebsite.com/8815/1.html
```

It supports numbers with leading zeros:

```
http://mywebsite.com/0001.html
```

[Example](//github.com/svnpenn/bm/blob/d0fe9e7/index.htm#L79-L81)

Answer (score 0):

Even if it is not a good way of doing what you want, try this hint:

```
var url = MUST BE A NUMBER FIRST
```

As in:

```
function nextImage () {
    url = url + 1;
    location.href = 'http://mywebsite.com/' + url + '.html';
}
```

Comment: I guess they were expecting you to show how to get the number.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is appending a "1" (the string) to your URL. If you want page 1.html link to page 2.html you need to take the 1 out of the string, add one to it, then reassemble the string.

Why not do something like this:

```
var url = 'http://mywebsite.com/1.html';
var pageNum = parseInt( url.split("/").pop(),10 );
var nextPage = 'http://mywebsite.com/'+(pageNum+1)+'.html';
```

nextPage will contain the url http://mywebsite.com/2.html in this case. Should be easy to put in a function if needed.