# how to detect current url when any change happened

Tags: jquery, url, location, href

I am stripping url with "document.location.hash" and trying to check whats left behind from current url. I dont want to use any plugin and dont want to learn result from trigger events like click. Need to learn url change instantly and contemporary.

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).location().change(function() {//this part is not working
        var anchor = document.location.hash;
        if( anchor === '#one' ) {
            alert('current url = #one');
        }else if ( anchor === '#two' ) {
            alert('current url = #two');
        }else if ( anchor === '#three' ) {
            alert('current url = #three');
        }
        console.log(anchor);
    });
});
```

html:

```
<a href="#one">one</a>
<a href="#two">two</a>
<a href="#three">three</a>
```

deep note: i have read these questions and cout find what i am looking for:
[How to detect URL change in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390341/how-to-detect-url-change) + [How to change the current URL in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866118/how-to-change-the-current-url-in-javascript)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without using a plugin other than jQuery, you can handle the 'hashchange' event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).bind( 'hashchange', function(e) { 
    var anchor = document.location.hash;
            if( anchor === '#one' ) {
                alert('url = #one');
            }else if ( anchor === '#two' ) {
                alert('url = #two');
            }else if ( anchor === '#three' ) {
                alert('url = #three');
            }
            console.log(anchor);
    });
});
```

**Caution:** [Not all browsers support the hashchange event.](http://caniuse.com/hashchange)

**Use with fallback:** You should [use Modernizr to detect if hashchangeEvent is supported](http://modernizr.com/docs/#features-html5) and if that support check fails then fallback to [Ben Alman's jQuery hashchange event plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/) and use @Baylor Rae's solution in your else block.

Comment: depends on what browsers barlasapaydin wants to support(http://caniuse.com/hashchange)

Answer (score 3):

You might find Ben Alman's jQuery [hashchange event plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/) helpful.

```
$(function(){

  // Bind the event.
  $(window).hashchange( function(){
    // Alerts every time the hash changes!
    alert( location.hash );
  });

  // Trigger the event (useful on page load).
  $(window).hashchange();

});
```