# Remove url when hover over a (possible?)

Tags: html, css, url, hyperlink, href

Is it possible to **remove** the **url** when you **hover** on an **a element**?

This is what I mean:

[image]

Comment: Why are you trying to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide link information at the bottom left/right of the browser on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30410748/how-to-hide-link-information-at-the-bottom-left-right-of-the-browser-on-hover)

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a bit of JavaScript.

Remove the `href=` attribute from the `<a>` tag and instead have a `onclick=...` attribute on the `<a>` or any other element.

Then in the `onclick` handler assign to `document.location`.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are trying to modify the current url address without changing pages.
Do you have a valid reason for this? As is it non standard it will appear as a malicious attack to a lot of users.

Without further information on what your trying to achieve, I can only say you shouldn't modify the url without changing page. Otherwise using JavaScript you can change the page, and URL without doing a full page change.

If you are trying to use ajax to change a page, and the url, without refreshing you should refer to other stack overflow questions below.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1865840/1246494

[Modify the URL without reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)

[How to change the current URL in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866118/how-to-change-the-current-url-in-javascript)

Other references.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location#Methods

Answer (score 0):

You cannot turn off the status bar. That's the status bar in Chrome and you have no controls over it

https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!category-topic/chrome/discuss-chrome/FtD7qjochgw

You could however use `pointer-events: none;` but that would disable the link also.